# Segmentation fault at the end of the program in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind

A segmentation fault occurs after everything has been executed. I tried for hours but still can't find the problem. I feel depressed and any assistance is appreciated!

All the code are under directory "KNN - GitHub" in this link: https://ide.c9.io/captainzidane/kd_tree
point.txt, test2.c, kdtree.c, kdtree.h are to be used.

Here is part of my "test.c" file, where the seg fault occurs at the last line. i.e., the last closing brace `}`

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "kdtree.h"

#define DEF_NUM_PTS 10
#define MAX_NUM_OF_POINTS 20000
#define DIMENSION 3



    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  //int arraySize; 
  double pointArray[MAX_NUM_OF_POINTS][DIMENSION];
  FILE *coordFile = fopen ("points.txt", "r");
  //coord *coords = malloc(sizeof(coord) * MAX_NUM_OF_POINTS);
  int lineCounter = 0;
  while (fscanf (coordFile, "%lf %lf %lf", &pointArray[lineCounter][0], &pointArray[lineCounter][1], 
                                           &pointArray[lineCounter][2]) == 3 && lineCounter < MAX_NUM_OF_POINTS) {
    lineCounter++;
  }
  double range = 8.1;
  int num_of_nearest;
  double queryPoint[DIMENSION];
  int counter;
  int dist;
  int num;
  //scanf ("%lf %lf %lf %d", &queryPoint[0], &queryPoint[1], &queryPoint[2], &num);
  queryPoint[0] = 1;
  queryPoint[1] = 5;
  queryPoint[2] = 8;
  num = 10;

  //Build and insert points to a KD Tree
  struct kdtree *newTree = buildTree (pointArray);//////make it run only once



  //Return nearst N nodes and distance in order from smallest to largest
  struct knn_result *res_n = knn(newTree, queryPoint, num);
  free (res_n);
  printf ("======================================================\n");


  //Return nodes within a range of the query point
  struct nn_range *res_range = nn_range(newTree, queryPoint, range);
  free (res_range);
  printf ("======================================================\n");


  fclose (coordFile);
  kd_free(newTree);///To be deleted
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the part of my "kdtree.c" file which contains the function which may cause the error:

```
struct nn_range {
    double nearestRange[MAX_NUM_OF_POINTS][DIMENSION+1];
    int nPoints;
};

struct nn_range *nn_range (struct kdtree *tree, const double *queryPoint, double range) 
{

  printf ("Nodes within a radius of %.3f to the query point:\n", range);
  printf ("-------------------------------------------------\n");

  struct kdres *presults_range = kd_nearest_range(tree, queryPoint, range); 
  double temp[3] = {0};
  double dist_temp = 0;

  struct nn_range *res = malloc(sizeof(struct nn_range));

  int counter = 0,i;

  res->nPoints = kd_res_size(presults_range);
  printf("found %d results within the radius of %.3f\n", res->nPoints, range);

  while(!kd_res_end( presults_range) && counter < res->nPoints) 
  {
    dist_temp = 0;
    /* get the data and position of the current result item */
    kd_res_item(presults_range, temp);

    /* compute the distance of the current result from the pt */
    for(i=0; i<DIMENSION; i++) 
    {
        dist_temp += SQ(queryPoint[i] - temp[i]);
    }
    dist_temp = sqrt(dist_temp);
    res->nearestRange[counter][0] = temp[0];
    res->nearestRange[counter][1] = temp[1];
    res->nearestRange[counter][2] = temp[2];
    res->nearestRange[counter][3] = dist_temp;

    /* print out the retrieved data */
    printf("node at (%.3f, %.3f, %.3f) is %.3f away\n", res->nearestRange[counter][0], 
                                                        res->nearestRange[counter][1],
                                                        res->nearestRange[counter][2],
                                                        res->nearestRange[counter][3]);

    /* go to the next entry */
    kd_res_next(presults_range);
    counter++;
  }

  kd_res_free(presults_range);
  return res;
}
```

GDB said

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400ab9 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe1d8) at test2.c:117
117     }
```

Valgrind said

```
==5369== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==5369==    at 0x3FE970FD6F3D35D2: ???
==5369==    by 0x3FED48EE17391B6D: ???
==5369==    by 0xFFF000157: ???
==5369==    by 0xFFFFFFFF: ???
==5369==    by 0x4008BC: ??? (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/KNN - GitHub/c)
==5369==  Address 0x3fe970fd6f3d35d2 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5369== 
==5369== 
==5369== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5369==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x3FE970FD6F3D35D2
==5369==    at 0x3FE970FD6F3D35D2: ???
==5369==    by 0x3FED48EE17391B6D: ???
==5369==    by 0xFFF000157: ???
==5369==    by 0xFFFFFFFF: ???
==5369==    by 0x4008BC: ??? (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/KNN - GitHub/c)
==5369== 
==5369== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5369==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5369==   total heap usage: 40,057 allocs, 40,057 frees, 2,561,888 bytes allocated
==5369== 
==5369== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5369== 
==5369== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==5369== 
==5369== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==5369== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==5369==    at 0x3FE970FD6F3D35D2: ???
==5369==    by 0x3FED48EE17391B6D: ???
==5369==    by 0xFFF000157: ???
==5369==    by 0xFFFFFFFF: ???
==5369==    by 0x4008BC: ??? (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/KNN - GitHub/c)
==5369==  Address 0x3fe970fd6f3d35d2 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5369== 
==5369== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

Here is part of the output

```
    Nodes within a radius of 8.100 to the query point:
-------------------------------------------------
found 24 results within the radius of 8.100
node at (0.718, 0.958, 0.994) is 8.093 away
node at (0.716, 0.974, 0.992) is 8.087 away
node at (0.629, 0.960, 0.991) is 8.099 away
node at (0.629, 0.960, 0.991) is 8.099 away
node at (0.556, 0.994, 0.979) is 8.096 away
node at (0.677, 0.985, 0.991) is 8.084 away
node at (0.556, 0.994, 0.979) is 8.096 away
node at (0.677, 0.985, 0.991) is 8.084 away
node at (0.909, 0.966, 0.980) is 8.097 away
node at (0.909, 0.966, 0.980) is 8.097 away
node at (0.909, 0.966, 0.980) is 8.097 away
node at (0.909, 0.966, 0.980) is 8.097 away
node at (0.978, 0.958, 0.993) is 8.089 away
node at (0.978, 0.958, 0.993) is 8.089 away
node at (0.978, 0.958, 0.993) is 8.089 away
node at (0.978, 0.958, 0.993) is 8.089 away
node at (0.857, 0.970, 0.978) is 8.098 away
node at (0.862, 0.985, 0.984) is 8.085 away
node at (0.862, 0.985, 0.984) is 8.085 away
node at (2.000, 2.000, 2.000) is 6.782 away
node at (2.000, 2.000, 2.000) is 6.782 away
node at (1.000, 1.000, 1.000) is 8.062 away
node at (1.000, 1.000, 1.000) is 8.062 away
node at (1.000, 2.000, 2.000) is 6.708 away
======================================================
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Hello! Did you already check if `counter` is always smaller than `MAX_NUM_OF_POINTS`?

Comment: ...and what is `DIMENSION` value?

Comment: Yes, and I used gdb info locals to double-check. counter is around 25 in this case and MAX_NUM_OF_POINTS is 20000. DIMENSION is 3, which means points are in 3D space.

Comment: Is this really all you get from Valgrind?

Comment: You also want to run Valgrind' s stack/Array checker on your program: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/sg-manual.html

Comment: It is from valgrind --leak-check=full -v

Comment: This stringly smells like an array-out-of-bound issue. See my link on the SGCheck tool above.

Comment: 0x3fe970fd6f3d35d2  is 0.795043, which is within the range of some of your array values, so it could be that a local array in `main` is being overflowed and values are being written to the part of the stack where the return address is kept. Can you show your code for `main`?

Comment: Try add flag -g to compiler  (generates additional debug information to be used by GDB debugger) It should help get better info from GDB and valgrind.

Comment: It is usually considered a bad practice to have a function with the same name as a struct (nn_range).

Comment: Ok I updated the main.

Comment: They are all the result after adding -g flag.

Comment: All the code are under directory "KNN - GitHub" in this link: https://ide.c9.io/captainzidane/kd_tree
point.txt, test2.c, kdtree.c, kdtree.h are to be used.

Comment: And the program runs well when I put "exit(1)" between "kd_free(newTree);" and  "return EXIT_SUCCESS;"

Comment: Could you change `fscanf (...) == 3 && lineCounter < MAX_NUM_OF_POINTS` to `lineCounter < MAX_NUM_OF_POINTS && fscanf (...) == 3` ?

Comment: @CuiZheng That makes sense. Your crash happens when `main` returns. `exit()` will terminate the program without `main`  returning.

Answer (score 3):

> A segmentation fault occurs after everything has been executed

In 99.9% of the cases this happens because you overflow a stack buffer allocated in `main`, and step on (corrupt) `main`s return address, so it returns to a "garbage" address.

> I tried for hours but still can't find the problem

There are a few ways to find such problems:

1. Code inspection. Now that you know what to look for, examine all stack buffers in `main`, and check that you don't write to any of them out of bounds.
2. Allocate an *extra* buffer of 256 bytes before your first stack buffer in `main`, and after the last such buffer. Fill these extra buffers with a known sentinel value, and verify that the sentinel values are still intact just before returning from `main`. They likely wouldn't be. Once you know which sentinel value is getting corrupted, use GDB watchpoint to find which code writes to that address.
3. Valgrind (which you have tried) is very weak at detecting stack overflows. You could convert some of your stack buffers to be heap-allocated, and Valgrind will tell you right away where the overflow happened.
4. If you have a relatively recent compiler, both Clang and GCC support [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (`-fsanitize=address`), which is excellent at detecting both heap *and* stack overflows, and will likely point you straight at the problem.

> All the code are under directory "KNN - GitHub"

That site requires a login. You don't seriously believe we all are going to sign up for an account there just so we can tell you exactly what the problem is? Next time, try to put your code somewhere more easily accessible.